# delete dirs in a specified period of time

Tags: directory

I have a list of +30.000 directory and I have to delete all the directories and their content from 2005 to 2006, via terminal.
Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you can use the following command:

```
$ find /path/to/dir -mtime +10 -exec /bin/rm -rf {} \;
```

This will remove all files/folders that are older than 10 days. There are other options like `-atime`. You can see `man find` for more info.

Comment: yes thanks but I don't want to delete folders older than 10 days, only from 01-01-2005 to 31-12-2006

Comment: So, you can find how many days your files are old and execute similar command. Do you have files older than 01-01-2005? If so, you can copy them to another directory.

Answer (score 2):

If you have GNU `find`, you can do this:

```
find /start/path -newermt 2004-12-31 ! -newermt 2006-12-31 -delete
```

Use `-ls` instead of `-delete` to test.